# How many ways to go up a N-step stairs?

Tags: c

Hello everyone :) today during class my teacher showed  us an "exam-like" program, and I tried to do it at home just to challenge myself. Given a N-steps stair, I can do normal steps (1 step at a time), 2 steps at once and 3 steps at once. How many different ways can I go up a N-step stair? The code returns me wrong output

```
    int N,sol1,sol2,sol3,somma,i;
    sol1=0;
    sol2=1;
    sol3=2;
    somma=0;
    i=0;


    printf("inserire numero scalini: ");
    scanf("%d",&N);

    if (N==1) {
        printf("\nil numero di possibilita' e' %d",N);
    }

    else if(N==2) {
        printf("\nil numero di possibilita' e' %d",N);

    }else{




    i=3;

    while (i<=N) {
        somma=sol1+sol2+sol3;
        sol1=sol2;
        sol2=sol3;
        sol1=somma;
        i++;
    }
}
    printf("\nil numero di modi e' %d",somma);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The code you pasted here has compiler errors because you are missing `int main()`. Also, what output are you getting? And what should the output be? Follow the steps [in this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) to debug your code and figure out where the problem is.

Comment: I’m sorry my bad for the int main part; if I put N=4 it should output 7, N=5 14; for every N (apart from N=1 and N=2) the total ways to go up the stair are the sum of the ways of the fewer steps stair (example; N=4 is 7 different ways, since for N=3 we have 4 ways, for N=2 2 ways  and N=1, 1 way). I’m getting for N=4, 8 and for N=5,11. By using bigger numbers the error grows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer by Code-Apprentice is very good, so I want to contribute a different approach:

Writing down the solutions for the first few flight of stairs I quickly noticed a pattern. Let's see:

```
total steps | steps taken   | ways to go up
------------x---------------x--------------
1           | 1             | 1
------------x---------------x--------------
2           | 2             | 2
            | 1, 1          |
------------x---------------x--------------
3           | 3             | 4
            | 2, 1          |
            | 1, 2          |
            | 1, 1, 1       |
------------x---------------x--------------
4           | 4             | 8
            | 3, 1          |
            | 2, 2          |
            | 2, 1, 1       |
            | 1, 3          |
            | 1, 2, 1       |
            | 1, 1, 2       |
            | 1, 1, 1, 1    |
```

So apparently for a flight of stairs with N-steps, there're 2^(N-1) ways to go up.
We don't even need recursion!
This solution is a lot quicker to execute and easier to maintain, but since you're trying to understand recursion, Code-Apprentice's answer is the way to go.

Comment: Very likely a formal analysis can prove that this is true for any `n`.

Answer (score 2):

The way to approach a problem like this is to step back from your code and describe a solution in English. So let's think through some examples:

1. If the stairs has 1 step, then there's one way to go up: take 1 step
2. If the stairs has 2 steps, then you have two choices:

   - Go up 1 step and then you have 1 step remaining (refer to case 1)
   - Go up 2 steps and then you are finished
3. If the stairs has 3 steps, then you have three choices:

   - Go up 1 step, and then you have 2 steps remaining (refer to case 2)
   - Go up 2 steps, and then you have 1 step remaining (refer to case 1)
   - Go up 3 steps, and then you are finished.
4. If the stairs has more than 3 steps, call this number `n`.

   - Go up 1 step, and then you have `n-1` steps remaining. (refer to case 1, 2, 3, or 4, depending on the value of `n-1`.
   - Go up 2 step, and then you have `n-2` steps remaining. (refer to case 1, 2, 3, or 4, depending on the value of `n-2`.
   - Go up 3 step, and then you have `n-2` steps remaining. (refer to case 1, 2, 3, or 4, depending on the value of `n-3`)

This description leads us to see a recursive relationship. The number of ways to traverse `n` steps is the same as the number of ways to traverse `n-1` steps plus the number of ways to traverse `n-2` steps the number of ways to traverse `n-3` steps.

To translate this all into code, I would write a function `go_up(n)` that implements the rules described above.